# Exclude whole word using regexp

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to exclude word `user` and `gallery` using regular expression.

```
^/(?!user|gallery)([a-z0-9_-]{3,64})$
```

My regexp also excludes words like `mygallery` (in which `gallery` is a **substring**). I want to have `mygallery` included.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Seems to do what you want if I've understood correctly?
http://regexr.com?35mqc

Comment: Is the slash there on purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex should already accept `mygallery`, but it would reject `username`. Add [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to make sure it doesn't:

```
^/(?!user$|gallery$)([a-z0-9_-]{3,64})$
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$str = "mygallery and gallery user and username";
echo preg_replace("/\bgallery\b|\buser\b/","",$str);
```

Output :

```
mygallery and and username
```